Aligning two time series with different resolution
There are two time series covering roughly the same interval prices (date date, price double) and rates (date date, rate double). The second one has higher resolution and more entries. How do I join them selecting the latest row from prices that is earlier for each row in rates? The dialect doesn't really matter but PostgreSQL is preferrable

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Also add the tag of rdbms which you use. All rdbms uses its own language dialect

So assuming your data looks somewhat like this:
with prices as (
    select * from (values (1, '2024-01-01'::timestamp, 10.0), (2, '2024-01-02'::timestamp, 10.1), (3, '2024-01-03'::timestamp, 10.2)) as t (id, date, price)
),
rates as (
    select * from (values 
      (0, '2023-12-31 12:00:00'::timestamp, 99.0),
        (1, '2024-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp, 11.0),
        (2, '2024-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp, 11.0),
        (3, '2024-01-01 13:00:00'::timestamp, 11.5),
        (4, '2024-01-01 14:00:00'::timestamp, 11.1),
        (5, '2024-01-02 12:00:00'::timestamp, 11.0),
        (6, '2024-01-02 13:00:00'::timestamp, 11.5),
        (7, '2024-01-02 14:00:00'::timestamp, 11.1),
        (8, '2024-01-03 12:00:00'::timestamp, 11.0),
        (9, '2024-01-03 13:00:00'::timestamp, 11.5),
        (10, '2024-01-03 14:00:00'::timestamp, 11.1)
    ) as t (id, date, rate)
)

You could use a subselect to get the price for each rate:
select
  rates.date, 
  rates.rate,
  (select price from prices where prices.date < rates.date order by date desc limit 1)
from rates

order by date and pick the first to get the right one. I'm assuming < is what you want because you've written "earlier". But it also depends what column types you have and what resolution. Perhaps you need to date_trunc to find the correct price.
You can also use this to join:
select 
    rates.date, 
    rates.rate,
    prices.price
from rates
left join prices on date_trunc('day', (rates.date - interval '1' day)) = date_trunc('day', prices.date)

Here i used a left join, since not every rate has an associated price. But this depends on your data.
